# Drag and Drop code that works on FireFox but not IE

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following drag-and-drop code. It works fine on Firefox but it does not work on IE.

```
//This function starts the event
function dragStart(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.effectAllowed= 'move'; //Makes the element movable
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("Image", ev.target.getAttribute('id')); // Grabs the element by its id
    return true;
}

//Prevents default but does not turn it off
function dragEnter(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    return true;
}

//Turns off the dragover event and prevents default behavior
function dragOver(ev) {
    return false;
}

//This function performs the actual drop
function dragDrop(ev) {
    var oldImgId = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Image"); //The dragged element’s id is set to a variable

    ev.preventDefault();
    moveImg(oldImgId);
}
```

I got these errors from IE when I attempt to drag an image:

1)

```
'target' is null or not an object line 71
line 71 refers to: ev.dataTransfer.setData("Image", ev.target.getAttribute('id')); // Grabs the element by its id
```

2)

```
Object doesn't support this property or method line 77
line 77 refers to: ev.preventDefault();
```

Comment: 1) does IE report an error? 2) do you have example that shows this - like jsfiddle.net

Comment: Please check my Edit on my question above, thanx

Comment: Can you please add the HTML or the code that shows how these events are attached.

Comment: can you try changing `function dragStart(ev) {`
 to `function dragStart(ev) { ev = (ev)?ev:window.event;`

Comment: Cross browser drag and drop using the drag and drop api is very tricky. I have a working example here which I wrote for a German magazin, hence the comments are in German. https://raw.github.com/tjunghans/DnD-Webstandards/master/public/article-beispiel.html. Use the code on my example to compare with your html, css and javascript (all matter). The best explanation on the web regarding dnd is found on http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2010/01/10/cross-browser-html5-drag-and-drop/.

Answer (score 1):

IE only supports Text or an URL as data, so 'Image' won't work. Try

```
ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.getAttribute('id'));
```

And here's the documentation:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536744(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I tried it but still not working, and I have the same errors.

I was able to fix the errors that I get on IE by replacing:
1) ev.dataTransfer.setData("Image", ev.target.getAttribute('id'));
with: 
var target= (ev.target) ? ev.target : ev.srcElement;
ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", target.getAttribute('id'));

2) ev.preventDefault();
with:
if (ev.preventDefault) { ev.preventDefault(); } else { ev.returnValue = false; }

now I don't get any errors from IE, but also the dragging still not working

Comment: Did you also change "Image" to "Text" for the following line? var oldImgId = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Image");

Comment: I don't understand, every thing seems fine. I tried to debug the dragStart in IE, when the function returns I got a strange error from the IE debugger "source code is not available for this location" I don't know what it means??!!

Comment: Would it be possible for you to post a link to your entire source code (html, css and javascript) for the drag and drop or create a fiddle? Also have you had a look at the example I posted in the comment in your question above? https://raw.github.com/tjunghans/DnD-Webstandards/master/public/article-beispiel.html

Comment: Thanks TJ for your help, I saw ur example and both are similer, except in the example u sent, it use DOM events (add handler), in mine I use Inline Html <img ondargstart='return dragstart(event)/> because the image are created dynamically; the program I do is just an exercise for me (Image Sliding Puzzel), there are alot of code in it, I don't know how to send it to u? Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use the jQuery UI drag & drop as it's designed to work with all current browsers.
http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/

http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable